# Powershell: The term 'powershell' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I need to run powershell/powershell.exe from commandline, in windows server 2016 which is a vm im vSphere, but it does not work, the error is as follows:
[image]

the goal I want to achive is to run powershell from remote "Ansible/pywinrm/winrm". and they use powershell commands. therefrore, alternatives are not helping because I can not replace them.

I will appriciate if anyone can help me to go forward.

what I done or checked:

1. installed powershell 7, after that this command: "pwsh" works, but "powershell" command not.
   2.check environment variables, and add powershell there:

```
$env: PATH
$env: psmodulePATH
```

3. tried this link:[Microsoft-starting powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/starting-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3)
   this path is given here:
   %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
   and it is instresting because when I run powershell direct from here, the there is more information after error, and when I run the command as bellow it works only on this powershell!

```
./powershell
```

[image]

and if I run the powershell with fullpath from a windows powershell it works as well
[image]

Comment: From the look of that prompt (eg "PS <folder path>") in your screenshots, it looks like you're already running Powershell, as you're running those commands within a Powershell prompt. So you're essentially trying to run powershell from within powershell?!?

Comment: yes powershell has itself the powershell command

Answer (score 0):

Try running `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

If it works, this means your `%Path%` is corrupt.

Try using the following command to fix it:

```
$sys_path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $sys_path -Name Path -Type String -Value $((Get-ItemProperty -Path $sys_path -Name Path).Path + ';C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0')
```

If it doesn't work, then it means your Windows system is corrupt.

Run the following commands to fix your OS:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

Reboot your computer then try to fix the `%PATH%` using my command.

Comment: I think you are right but the problem still exist. I done both of your suggestions.

Comment: it is funny now! :)) I add this path you told to the path, it works and then when I close the windows it does not work again. windows will automatically remove the path from environment each time(I run as admin)